# Missing required argument '<PROVIDER>'. Scafffold Dbcontext in asp.net core 2.1.MAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

Trying to do Scaffold with the existing database in mac os visual studio using terminal.

Here is the command for the scaffold

```
dotnet ef dbcontext Scaffold "Server=<servername>;Initial Catalog=<dbName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<rental>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model
```

[image: dependencies]

[image: error details]

But keep getting an error as **Missing required argument ''.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

Comment: Your question not clear. May be getting error for other things

Comment: When I tried to create scaffold from exiting database using terminal in mac .. I am getting that error. Their is no other error on project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing a space between the connection string and the provider type:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
    "Server=<servername>;…Timeout=30;"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model

                                     ↑↑
```

So you are only passing a single argument to the command, making the provider name missing.

Comment: I wish this was my problem.  Stupid MS tools.